# Dynamically download the .js(All components) files from server when app starts from the mobile device

Tags: mobile, apk, react-native, react-native-ios

The Requirement,
We will be having the contents (Components.Js files, Assets like images etc) in the Web server.
When my app is launched from the mobile device, apk in will make an request to download the files from my webserver and start loading the app.

So that my apk will only hols the App.Js and request urls to fetch all the Components from the Server.

Is it possible in React Native.? Or Is there any way to achieve this .?

Comment: Maybe you don't wanna use react native if you're going to be loading your whole app externally.. You could use ionic or other libraries of that nature

Comment: Not the entire app externally, We are trying to reduce the APK size and dependency on the code, 
Like When then the application is loaded from app.js we will load all the reusable component(Form.Js) files instead of bundling the js files into APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like codepush
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push
to update code OTA without publishing new update via play/app store